# How can I read a body of a received push notification?

Tags: swift

Sorry for the possible stupid question. My application receives Push Notifications with help of Firebase. I need to put the body of a received push notifications into a string var and display this var in the next view controller. How can I do it?

I tried as

```
func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
           notificationText = response.notification.request.content.body
```

And it does not work

I tried as

```
let pushContent = UNNotificationContent()
notificationText = pushContent.body
```

and it also does not work

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the `body`, the custom data is available in `userInfo` property.
For remote notifications, this property contains the entire notification payload.

```
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
debugPrint(userInfo)
```

If you define the notification payload data as custom decodable type, you can easily retrieve the properties as follows.

```
struct PushNotificationData: Decodable {
    let aps: Aps
    let customData: String?
    
    init(decoding userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo, options: .prettyPrinted)
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(PushNotificationData.self, from: data)
    }
}

struct Aps: Decodable {
    let alert: Alert
    let sound: String
}

struct Alert: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let body: String
}
```

Inside `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler)` method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    debugPrint(userInfo)

    if let pushNotiData = try? PushNotificationData(decoding: userInfo), let customData = pushNotiData.customData {
        debugPrint(customData)
        // This customData can be stored or used for any purpose.
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you recommended and got userInfo. But if let pushNotiData = try? PushNotificationData(decoding: userInfo) does not work. So I canot get customData

Comment: I am sorry but I checked once more and this works: 

func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
           notificationText = response.notification.request.content.body}

Comment: @IhorDolhalov I am glad that your notificationText works.  For the decoding of `PushNotificationData` to work, `customData` should be the key name from your notification payload. For example, if your backend push noti contains the `userRole: "admin"` as additional key-value pair, replace `customData` with `userRole`.